# mark as read when a product order is views with id. In Django rest framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, mvt

This is my models

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and this is my views

```
class NotificationListCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Notification.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NotificationSerializer


class NotificationDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Notification.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NotificationSerializer
```

In my NotificationDetailView I want to add functionality when a notification views in detail
the is_read field should True.

Answer (score 1):

Update the item with:

```
class NotificationDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Notification.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NotificationSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        item = super().get_object()
        item.is_read = True
        item.save(update_fields=('is_read',))
        return item
```

this will set the item on `is_read` *before* serializing it. We can also do this *after* serializing it with:

```
class NotificationDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Notification.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NotificationSerializer

    def retrieve(self, *args, **kwargs):
        response = return super().retrieve(*args, **kwargs)
        item = self.get_object()
        item.is_read = True
        item.save(update_fields=('is_read',))
        return response
```

but this will make one additiona query.